# Javascript 3D convex-hull algorithm similar to Matlab's convhulln

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matlab, convex-hull

I've been struggling to find a convex-hull library for Javascript that gives the same output as the Matlab convhulln function.

I am transcribing some code from Matlab to Javascript and I need to find triangles that make up the convex hull of a set of vertices. Matlab calculates the convex hull of some 3D points using convhulln (which makes use of the qhull function). In this case Matlab convhulln outputs a different set of triangle faces to that of quickhull3d when I pass the same vertices to each. Some faces coincide but in general most do not. The only similarity they have is they both output the same number of faces (although the actual vertices of the faces are not the same).

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhulln.html

In Javascript, I've tried different libraries and each one gives a different output..

From npm I've tried:

`quickhull3d` - https://github.com/maurizzzio/quickhull3d

```
convex-hull

delaunay-triangulate
```

most other algorithms have been designed for 2D points, so I have ruled them out.

Any thoughts, tips or feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Here are the vertices I'm using and the results of both MATlab's convhulln and quickhull3d. Please note I've used a sorting algorithm to sort them in the from first vertices to last. This should not effect the actual triangle faces since I sorted them in exactly the same way in both the MATlab and JS code.

Here are plots of the two hulls.

[image: Matlab Convex Hull]

[image]

Notice the holes. I have spoken to the developer of the quickhull3d algorithm (thanks for your response!!) and he has suggested it might be that the triangulation process he used is different to one matlab uses.

```
vertices = [ 
  [ 0.9510565162951535, -0.3090169943749474, 0 ],
  [ 0.5877852522924731, -0.8090169943749475, 0 ],
  [ 6.123233995736766e-17, -1, 0 ],
  [ -0.5591929034707466, 0.8290375725550418, 0 ],
  [ -0.9510565162951535, -0.3090169943749475, 0 ],
  [ -0.9510565162951536, 0.3090169943749473, 0 ],
  [ -0.5877852522924732, 0.8090169943749473, 0 ],
  [ -1.8369701987210297e-16, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0.5877852522924729, 0.8090169943749476, 0 ],
  [ 0.9510565162951535, 0.3090169943749476, 0 ],
  [ 0.984807753012208, 0, -0.17364817766693033 ],
  [ 0.30432233187297814, -0.9366078308002486, -0.17364817766693033 ],
  [ -0.796726208379082, -0.5788554735638644, -0.17364817766693033 ],
  [ -0.7967262083790821, 0.5788554735638641, -0.17364817766693033 ],
  [ 0.3043223318729779, 0.9366078308002487, -0.17364817766693033 ],
  [ 0.5000000000000001, -0.5, 0.7071067811865475 ],
  [ -0.5, -0.5000000000000001, 0.7071067811865475 ],
  [ -0.5000000000000001, 0.5, 0.7071067811865475 ],
  [ 0.4999999999999999, 0.5000000000000001, 0.7071067811865475 ],
  [ 6.123233995736766e-17, 0, 1 ] 
]
```

triangles from quickhull3d:
dim = 36x3

```
    trianglesqh = [ 
  [ 0, 1, 11 ],
  [ 0, 9, 18 ],
  [ 0, 10, 9 ],
  [ 0, 11, 10 ],
  [ 0, 15, 1 ],
  [ 0, 18, 15 ],
  [ 1, 2, 11 ],
  [ 1, 15, 2 ],
  [ 2, 12, 11 ],
  [ 2, 15, 16 ],
  [ 2, 16, 12 ],
  [ 3, 6, 17 ],
  [ 3, 7, 14 ],
  [ 3, 13, 6 ],
  [ 3, 14, 13 ],
  [ 3, 17, 7 ],
  [ 4, 5, 13 ],
  [ 4, 12, 16 ],
  [ 4, 13, 12 ],
  [ 4, 16, 17 ],
  [ 4, 17, 5 ],
  [ 5, 6, 13 ],
  [ 5, 17, 6 ],
  [ 7, 8, 14 ],
  [ 7, 17, 18 ],
  [ 7, 18, 8 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10 ],
  [ 8, 10, 14 ],
  [ 8, 18, 9 ],
  [ 10, 11, 12 ],
  [ 10, 12, 14 ],
  [ 12, 13, 14 ],
  [ 15, 18, 19 ],
  [ 15, 19, 16 ],
  [ 16, 19, 17 ],
  [ 17, 19, 18 ] 
]
```

triangles from MATlab:
dim = 36x3

```
trianglesm = [
  [ 0, 1, 11 ],
  [ 0, 9, 18 ],
  [ 0, 10, 9 ],
  [ 0, 11, 10 ],
  [ 0, 15, 1 ],
  [ 0, 18, 15 ],
  [ 1, 2, 11 ],
  [ 1, 18, 2 ],
  [ 2, 3, 11 ],
  [ 2, 15, 16 ],
  [ 2, 16, 3 ],
  [ 3, 4, 12 ],
  [ 3, 12, 11 ],
  [ 3, 16, 4 ],
  [ 4, 5, 12 ],
  [ 4, 17, 5 ],
  [ 5, 8, 13 ],
  [ 5, 13, 12 ],
  [ 5, 16, 17 ],
  [ 5, 17, 6 ],
  [ 6, 7, 14 ],
  [ 6, 14, 13 ],
  [ 6, 17, 7 ],
  [ 7, 8, 14 ],
  [ 7, 17, 18 ],
  [ 7, 18, 8 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10 ],
  [ 8, 10, 14 ],
  [ 8, 18, 9 ],
  [ 10, 11, 14 ],
  [ 11, 12, 13 ],
  [ 11, 13, 14 ],
  [ 15, 18, 19 ],
  [ 15, 19, 16 ],
  [ 16, 19, 17 ],
  [ 17, 19, 18 ]
]
```

Comment: Turns out my original sorting algorithm was incorrect. This still does not solve the problem.. Have uploaded new triangle faces after changes to sort algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Bowyer-Watson algorithm but with circumsphere and tetrahedrons:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm.

Comment: This is the standard "not an answer". Link only answer, with no explanation, or anything.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. Still struggling to get this working :/